# check if two select statement return same result on the given data set

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-except

```
(select * from query1 EXCEPT select * from query2)
 UNION ALL 
(select * from query2 EXCEPT select * from query1)
```

I have come across above query to solve the issue.
I did some trial on postgres 9.4, and here are my results.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727882/check-if-two-selects-are-equivalent) Minus is not supported,so need to use EXCEPT

[2] Using only EXCEPT does not consider duplicates so had to use EXCEPT ALL

[3] EXCEPT ALL require that column order in the resultant should be same so in above query `QUERY1` and `QUERY2` should either return the same column order or we have to wrap the query and make sure the column order are same.(may be this happens in application logic)

***So if we keep above three point in mind we will be 100% sure about our result right ?***

NOTE: I have also mentioned the above 3 points in the answer to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727882/check-if-two-selects-are-equivalent).
I have asked it here so that i can be sure

Comment: Without primary keys, this query makes little sense. In case you *really* need it, why not `select * from q1 union select * from q2` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you still are not guaranteed, as you can readily see from this example:

```
select *
from (select 1 as x union all select 1) x
except
select 1;
```

This returns 0 rows even though the two queries are not the same.

The problem is duplicates.

One method is to convert all the values in a row to a common value.  Postgres has an interesting syntax for this:

```
select table_alias::text
from (. . . ) table_alias
```

This concatenates all the values together.  You can then use this in a `row_number()` expression.  You could plug this into the `except` expression you have.  The addition of `row_number()` will fix the problem with duplicates.  The use of:

```
row_number() over (order by q1::text)
```

will guarantee that identical rows are in the same order.

Comment: in the query if you use `except all` instead on `except` then duplicate will be resolved right.. i have mention that in point [2]