# MySQL SELECT from table where row = (SELECT val1, val2, val3, ... etc.)

Tags: php, mysql, exists

I'd like to check if row exists, but without telling the column names, but only its values. IE.

```
+------+------+------+
|field1|field2|field3|
+------+------+------+
| abc  | cba  |  val |
+------+------+------+

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ... = (SELECT 'abc', 'cba', 'val')
```

Is it possible?

I'm writing a function in php and I'd like to add a row if such row doesn't exist. Function would take `n` parameters, ie.

```
addNewRowIfDoesNotExist('table1', 'abc', 'cba', 'val');
```

I don't want to modify the singature of function, but i need to check if such row exist in table as told. So I'm not passing column names. So how can i check does row exist without telling the col names?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Not knowing the names of your columns doesn't sound like a wise or scalable design pattern.

Comment: Making your code dependent on the ordering of your columns is a bad idea. Consider something like: `addNewRowIfDoesNotExist('table', ['field1' => 'abc', 'field2' => 'cba'])`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for comments. I've found it on the internet.

[check if two "select"s are equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727882/check-if-two-selects-are-equivalent) 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/

Thanks.
Mike

If you would like to see what I mean, there you go:

```
function insertRecordIntoTableIfNotExist()
{
    if (func_num_args() < 2)
        exit("Too few arguments at insertRecordIntoTableIfNotExist()<br>");

    $str = changeTableIntoStringWithCommasAndQuotes(func_get_args());
    $firstComma = strpos($str, ",");

    $tableName = substr($str, 0, $firstComma);
    $tableName = substr($tableName, 1, strlen($tableName) - 2);
    $rest = substr($str, $firstComma + 1);

    $result = executeQuery("SELECT " . $rest . " MINUS SELECT * FROM " . $tableName . "_v;");

    if ($result != FALSE)
        if (hasRows($result))
            return;

    if (executeQuery("INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " VALUES(NULL, " . $rest . ");") == FALSE)
    {
        printWrongQuery();

        exit("Error while inserting at insertRecordIntoTableIfNotExist()<br>");
    }
}
```

You need to specify a new View before you run this function. My tables has at first place `id`, so in view, I don't take it.

Comment: Please use the comments feature for comments.

Comment: I've used answer feature, cause it is a solution of my problem. I just

select my_data MINUS select * from MY_VIEW;
if result has 0 ROWS, my_data is in table, otherwise it isn't