# How to determine if data in two SQL tables are identical?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a temp table like this:

`DECLARE @Old TABLE ([Id] INT)`

And another one like this (identical structure)

`DECLARE @New TABLE ([Id] INT)`

I'm populating each of these tables in a cursor, and i want to know if the tables are identical. It should only be TRUE if:

1. Number of rows are identical
2. Values are identical

Order of rows does not matter.

Is there an easy/quick way to do this? The similar questions only see to deal with one way, not both ways. (e.g `EXCEPT` or `LEFT JOIN` will only work one way, unless repeated then combined somehow?)

Thanks

Comment: @MitchWheat care to chuck up an answer with an example pls?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727882/check-if-two-selects-are-equivalent

Comment: Begs the question: why are you using a cursor? It's almost the worst thing you can possibly do in SQL